# Silverlight Save Game Data

Tags: silverlight, load, save

I have a Game I'm developing in Silverlight, and I'm to the point where I'm ready to deal with saving and loading games (I realize I should have dealt with this sooner...). The Data Types I need to save are `Point`, `List<String>`, `Dictionary<Point, Room>` (Room is a custom class), and a couple other custom classes.

How might I save/load these data types in a Silverlight Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize them to Isolated Storage. If you are afraid of users messing with the save data you should send the data to a server and store them online.

This requires your classes to be serializable or implement your own serialization mechanism.